# Hive - Quering for results within a category after the occurrence of 1 category

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

All,

I'm a newbie at SQl/Hive and had an issue with developing a query which encompasses the same category.

I need to find out the user's activity for categories like Searched and Purchased when the user has registered within a given month.

E.g How many users are active once they register within a given month

```
User_ID      Date              Category
2           2/1/2014          Purchased
1           2/4/2014          Searched
1           2/8/2014          Registered
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you've tried so far and what results that gave?

Comment: I'm too embarrassed to post this but here is what I have so far. I am way off                                                           select t.user_id,t.category, count(t.category) from table t
join
(select category from table t where category in ('Searched','Purchased)) t2
on t.category = t2.category
where t.category='Registered'
group by t.user_id,t.subcategory

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to avoid the self-join.  It sounds like you essentially want to collect all the events for a user on a given month, and see if there were more than just the registration event.  This is described in the Brickhouse blog posting at http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/use-collect-to-avoid-the-self-join/

In your case, I think the query looks something like this:

```
select count(*), mnth
 from 
   ( select user_id, month(date) mnth, collect( category ) cat_array
      from table
      group by user_id, month(date) ) col_query
 where
   size( cat_array ) > 1
 and 
   array_contains( cat_array, 'Registered' )
 group by mnth;
```